# what is the kafka command that print the kafka machines names that equivalent to brokers id's numbers

Tags: linux, apache-kafka

we are using Kafka `version - 2.7.1`. cluster includes 5 Kafka machines on Linux `RHEL 7.6` version

in order to find the brokers ids number , we can ask the zookeeper server as the following

```
/usr/bin/zookeeper-shell  ZOO_SERVER:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids"
Connecting to ZOO_SERVER:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005]
```

so we know from above that brokers ids are - 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005

**the question that I want to ask now:**

how to know the Kafka machines names that equivalent brokers id's numbers?

I know that kafka01 is broker id 1001 and kafka02 is broker id 1002 , and so on , and this we can verified from `meta.properties` file on which broker!

example

```
more meta.properties
#
#Mon Jun 21 10:41:58 UTC 2021
cluster.id=SZtPtVDBS1eTZsPRwhmnpg
version=0
broker.id=1004
```

** but we not want to perform ssh connection to each Kafka broker/s ( kafka01-05 ) and verify the file `meta.properties`

So I want to know if we can use some *Kafka cli* that show exactly the `Kafka names` that are relevant for the `brokers id's`

for example , expected results ( below are only example to what we want to get )

```
1001 --> kafka01
1002 --> kafka02
1003 --> kafka03
1004 --> kafka04
1004 --> kafka04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the endpoint name by the following zookeeper command

```
zookeeper-shell.sh [ZK_IP] get /brokers/ids/1001
```

---

In relation to your other question
by calling zookeeper-shell.sh twice, we can get directly the broker name that is the active controller, instead of the broker id.

```
zookeeper-shell.sh [ZK_IP] get /brokers/ids/$(zookeeper-shell.sh [ZK_IP] get /controller|tail -1|jq .brokerid)|tail -1|jq .endpoints[]
```